# Converting Django project from Python 2 to Python 3: How to fix Python int OverFlowError?

Tags: python, django, python-2to3

I am converting a Django website from Python 2 to Python 3. To do this, I ran 2to3 on the whole project. Now, upon running the server (which works fine in Python 2), an `OverflowError` occurs as shown in the first code block. The lower block shows the `manage.py` file.

I have read elsewhere this may be an issue relating to int/float, but I am not quite sure how to handle an iterator with regard to this.

```
(env) user:languages user$ python3 manage.py runserver
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../src/languages/env/bin/../lib/python3.7/site.py", line 66, in <module>
    import os
  File ".../src/languages/env/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 661, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "...src/languages/env/bin/../lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py", line 45, in <module>
    longrange_iterator = type(iter(list(range(1 << 1000))))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_tappleperson
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I expected manage.py to run the server as normal and produce the website but instead it gets hungup on the overflow error described above.

Comment: What kind of system are you working on (64bit/32bit) and how have you installed `python3.7`?

Comment: Are you running under a different implementation of Python?  Something seems very off about your setup here... there's no reason it should be failing on that line. :-(

Comment: @FlyingTeller 64 bit osx, python 3.7 installed virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code in [_collections_abc.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L45), in the Python 3 version, is:

```
longrange_iterator = type(iter(range(1 << 1000)))
```

Your version is

```
longrange_iterator = type(iter(list(range(1 << 1000))))
```

It looks like you used 2to3 on the Python3 code as well. `range` created a list in Python 2, so the exact equivalent in Python 3 would be  `list(range(...))`, which seems to be the replacement that took place here. It fails, as it forces the code to create a gigantic list, which the original does not.

So, when using 2to3, only apply it to the Python 2 code.